# Spring Cloud Gateway with Eureka discovery locator - 404

Tags: java, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm setting up a microservices based application using Spring Cloud Gateway with Eureka discovery client.

I have configured the Eureka server application, the Gateway application and a regular service.

I have set spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled and spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id to true in the Gateway application.yml file.

All three applications start correctly, however when I try to access the microservice through the Gateway I get a 404 error, sending a GET request to localhost:8080/event

I have configured actuator to display the endpoints exposed by the Gateway and there is an entry for the service.

What am I missing?

## Eureka Server application.yml

```
spring:
    application:
        name: registry
server:
    port: 8081

eureka:
    client:
        register-with-eureka: false
        fetch-registry: false
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
        prefer-ip-address: true
```

## Spring Cloud Gateway application.yml

```
spring:
    application:
        name: api-gateway
    cloud:
        gateway:
            discovery:
                locator:
                    enabled: true
                    lower-case-service-id: true
    main:
        web-application-type: reactive

server:
    port: 8080

eureka:
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:8081/eureka/
        fetch-registry: true
        register-with-eureka: true
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
        prefer-ip-address: true

management:
  endpoint:
    gateway:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - "*"
```

## Service application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  application:
    name: event

eureka:
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:8081/eureka/
        fetch-registry: true
        register-with-eureka: true
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
        prefer-ip-address: true
```

I have included the required annotations on both Eureka server application and Gateway and Event service application classes. I get the following response when querying http://localhost:8080/actuator/gateway/routes:

```
[{"predicate":"Paths: [/api-gateway/**], match trailing slash: true","metadata":{"jmx.port":"55939","management.port":"8080"},"route_id":"ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_API-GATEWAY","filters":["[[RewritePath /api-gateway/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"],"uri":"lb://API-GATEWAY","order":0},{"predicate":"Paths: [/event/**], match trailing slash: true","metadata":{"jmx.port":"55880","management.port":"8082"},"route_id":"ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_EVENT","filters":["[[RewritePath /event/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]"],"uri":"lb://EVENT","order":0}]
```

## EventController

```
package example.event.endpoint.controller;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import example.event.endpoint.service.EventService;
import example.core.model.Event;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/event")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class EventController {
    private final EventService eventService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Event>> listAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.info("Retrieving all events");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(eventService.list(pageable), OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the path you are trying to access? Based on routes events service should be accible via a gateway with something like - http://localhost:8080/event/someurl

This would forward the /someurl to the event service provided that service has the someurl endpoint

Comment: Simply localhost:8080/event . EventController only has a single mapping to the empty path

Comment: I have edited the question to add the Controller class and the URL I'm trying to hit.

Comment: If localhost:8082/v1/event returns your desired output I would expect the same from gateway localhost:8080/event/v1/event to route based on your configuration.

Comment: @Dhananjay, your reply solved the mystery. localhost:8080/event/v1/event gave the expected response. Since the goal is to use the Gateway to access all services, I'll remove the paths from the Controller classes, so Event service could be accessed like localhost:8080/v1/event. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Cool, I will post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `localhost:8082/v1/event` returns your desired output I would expect the same from gateway `localhost:8080/event/v1/event` to route based on your configuration.

The first `/event` is your service name used by the spring cloud gateway to determine which service it needs to route. By default, the service name gets trimmed, and the `/v1/event` path along with any other request part is routed to your event service.